# filtering units out of a sum based on dwell time

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a viz showing the financial impact of having trucks sit on the lot for extended periods of time. At the top, I have individual blocks of relevant information (current year sales/ previous year sales/ current year gross margin/ previous year gross margin etc). 
Anyway, these blocks are calculated by Count() and Sum() functions. 
I want to add a sliding filter of 'days on the lot' that would change these numbers accordingly. Is there a way to keep the summed figures and have them change by excluding trucks based on dwell time?

Comment: Do you have 'days on the lot' as a measure in your data source?

Comment: @dkritz or even arrival and departure times from the lot(s).